# PID control achieves zero steady state error with step set points and disturbances?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, steady-state

How can I explain this with proper reasoning?

I'm also having doubt understanding why a proportional controller cannot eliminate SSE and how a PI controller eliminates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the integrator.  An integrator will cause the smallest error to increase without limit (at least until saturation, or until the control circuit drives the error to zero).

[image]

So any difference between the reference and the feedback will cause the integrator output to change to the point where it drives the error to zero (and therefore there's no further change in the output of the integrator.)

With only a proportional gain there has to be some residual error to be multiplied by the gain in order to drive the error to as small a value as it can be, but it won't be zero.  A control system with a single integrator is type I:

[image]

Comment: thanks that makes sense , so this steady sate error is also called the offset right ? and PI controller eliminates it by integrating the error as long as the processed variable reaches set point . i guess the same happens for PID controller , but what about the disturbances ? can it still produce a zero SSE with disturbances ? @john D

Comment: If the disturbance is a step or finite it can produce a zero steady-state error.  However if the disturbance is a ramp for example you need a higher order control to get zero error.  Answer edited to add more information.